# How to get csv with header from xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a tei listPerson

```
<listPerson xml:id="person">
                    <person xml:id="abbadie_jacques">
                        <persName ref="http://d-nb.info/gnd/100002307">
                            <forename>Jacques</forename>
                            <surname>Abbadie</surname>
                        </persName>
                        <note>Prediger der französisch-reformierten Gemeinde in <rs type="place"
                                ref="#berlin">Berlin</rs></note>
                    </person>
                    <person xml:id="achermann_johann_jakob">
                        <persName ref="http://d-nb.info/gnd/1072413450">
                            <forename>Johann Jakob</forename>
                            <surname>Achermann</surname>
                        </persName>
                    </person>
           <person xml:id="aerschot_philipp">
                <persName ref="http://d-nb.info/gnd/132281007">
                    <forename>Philipp III.</forename>
                    <nameLink>von</nameLink>
                    <surname type="toponymic">
                        <rs type="place">Aarschot</rs>
                    </surname>
                    <roleName>Herzog</roleName>
                </persName>
                <note>Philippe de Croy</note>
            </person>
            <person xml:id="aham_barbara">
                <persName>
                    <forename>Barbara</forename>
                    <nameLink>von</nameLink>
                    <surname>Aham</surname>
                </persName>
                <note>Äbtissin Barbara II. des <rs type="place" ref="#niedermuenster_stift">Niedermünsters zu Regensburg</rs></note>
            </person>
</listPerson>
```

from which I want to generate a csv, which I then want to enrich with openrefine (I haven't looked into this, though)

My xslt-stylesheet looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
           <xsl:template name="header" match="persName">
                <xsl:for-each select="persName/*">
                    <xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
           </xsl:template> 

            
    <xsl:template name="test" match="persName" >
        <xsl:value-of select="persName/@ref"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="persName/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:template>
            
        <xsl:template match="person">
            <xsl:call-template name="header"></xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:value-of select="@xml:id"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="test"></xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As for the names tec. I get the output I wish, but for the header template, I am doing sth. wrong, as I get the following output:

```
        forenamesurnameabbadie_jacques;http://d-nb.info/gnd/100002307;Jacques;Abbadie;
        forenamesurnameachermann_johann_jakob;http://d-nb.info/gnd/1072413450;Johann Jakob;Achermann;
```

**this is outdated!**

> I, however, need the output to be
>
> ```
> forename; surname; linksurname;  
> jaques; abaddie; ;
> ```

I do not only have these three children but several more, but not every entry has every child.
**this clearly was untrue ** I guess I'm off to a good start ...

For reference:
@Martin Honnen gave a great answer, BUT I sucked at giving an example, so I hereby say "sorry" and added the specialties in my example above

Edit2 to improve my example:
the above xml should result in this input:

```
forename;nameLink;surname;roleName;gnd;note
Jacques;;Abbadie;;http://d-nb.info/gnd/100002307;
Johann Jakob;;Achermann;;http://d-nb.info/gnd/1072413450;
Philipp III.;von;Aarschot;Herzog;http://d-nb.info/gnd/132281007;Philippe de Croy
Barbara;von;Aham;;;Äbtissin Barabara II des Niedermünsters zu Regensburg
```

complexities and irregularities are really bad, some do not have a gnd-identifier, some have `<rs>` in their name-elements and note-elements.
I have several thousand entries, I think I found the most complex one.

Sorry for the poor initial question.
any help would be really appreciated,
All the best,
K

Comment: Is "linksurname" supposed to be read from or extracted from the XML? Also, do you use an XSLT 2 processor?

Comment: ha, I forgot a space there, output should be with all children of persName There might be <person>-element that has all these elements. Output isn't identical each time, some elements have a role attribute, some don't etc.

Comment: This is quite confusing. Do you really want each person to have their own header? If yes, why would any field be empty (as shown in your expected output)? And you still haven't  explained where `linksurname` comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (!) you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0/2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/listPerson">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>forename;nameLink;surname;roleName;gnd;note&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="person/persName">
        <xsl:value-of select="forename"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="nameLink"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="surname"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="roleName"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@ref"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../note"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result:

```
forename;nameLink;surname;roleName;gnd;note
Jacques;;Abbadie;;http://d-nb.info/gnd/100002307;Prediger der französisch-reformierten Gemeinde in Berlin
Johann Jakob;;Achermann;;http://d-nb.info/gnd/1072413450;
Philipp III.;von;Aarschot;Herzog;http://d-nb.info/gnd/132281007;Philippe de Croy
Barbara;von;Aham;;;Äbtissin Barbara II. des Niedermünsters zu Regensburg
```

is slightly different from the one you show - but I believe that's an omission on your part.

Comment: I think you think correctly. At least from my edited example, for the first iteration of which, I am truly to be punished. It still doesn't resolve the issue with nested tags, however. AS can be seen in the third and fourth example (in the XML there is a `note` with a `rs` inside. In example 3 there's a `surname` with a `rs` inside. I am not too sure about that. VS code is showing some tabs everytime this occurs. In Excel I get a super weird formatted view.

Comment: I don't see why the `rs` child elements are a problem. The stylesheet outputs the string-value of the parent `note` or `surname` element which is the concatenation of the string-values of all its descendant text node - including the text node/s of the `rs` child element/s. Make sure to include the `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` instruction to prevent the input's indentation from being passed to the output as well.

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT 2 or 3, I usually prefer to use `xsl:value-of separator` to construct the lines of CSV e.g.

```
  <xsl:param name="columns" as="xs:string*" select="'forename', 'surname', 'linksurname'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="$columns" separator=";"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//person/persName"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="person/persName">
      <xsl:value-of select="forename, surname, @ref" separator=";"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
```

For the more complex input you could use

```
  <xsl:param name="columns" as="xs:string*" select="'forename', 'nameLink', 'surname', 'roleName', 'gnd', 'note'"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="$columns" separator=";"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//person/persName"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="person/persName">
      <xsl:value-of select="(string(forename), string(nameLink), string(surname), string(roleName), string(@ref), string(../note)) ! normalize-space()" separator=";"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: With this I get the line over every entry, obviously I only need a header once. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: @KWunsch, your own code seems to call the header template for each person so I tried to implement that following that approach. Of course you can output the header line only once, will edit the answer.

Comment: Probably my code and my description was unclear. Sorry for that! :-(

Comment: The solution works great, only if I get nested so at times I have a ´´´<surname><rs type="place" ref="xxx"> Text </rs> </surname>´´´ in these cases, a line break is introduced. This is absolutely m fault, I should have picked better examples from the list (I was lazy and picked the first two entries :-D )

Comment: @KWunsch, it is hard to write generic code to map XML to CSV,  if the input is different from the one you have posted and is nested try to adapt the XPath selections in the value-of instructions, if that doesn't work out post a new question with the exact XML input structure and the exact CSV structure you want to generate, plus the XSLT you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: I figured as much! I have reframed my example above, so that it reflects two easy cases and I guess the most complex entry. I fear, however, that I have everything in between ...

Comment: @KWunsch, please edit the question to explain and show exactly the CSV you want to generate from those rather variable input structure.